# How to check the radio button in which id field is blank using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is sample html code

```
<div class="radioOff">
    <input id="" class="hidden" type="radio">
    <label for="">already a member</label>
    <span class="identity">identify</span>
</div>
```

I tried using 
`document.getElementById("").checked = true;`
its not working.

I can not do any change in code . 
Here is that third party website where I need to select radio button
http://www.degriftour-selection.fr/login.html

Comment: The only right course of action is to fix your HTML and don't use an empty ID attribute.

Comment: could you explain ,why did you keep id empty?

Comment: Careful, using the "hidden" class as selector, sounds like a class that could be used for other stuff then just that single input.

Comment: Its a tird party website so i can do any changes in code

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(".hidden[id='']").prop("checked",true);
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/9rJY8/)

Comment: I just tried for following website
http://www.degriftour-selection.fr/login.html
But its not working

Comment: @pravinkottawar You have two `.hidden` elements having blank IDs. IDs must be unique. Also, on your site, you use different code to select radio buttons. You are using images to show selected radio button. Show full code, it would be easier to understand.

Comment: Hiral this is not my website its third party site whatever code we can see using view source that is only one option

Comment: @pravinkottawar this might help: `$("#signup-form .hidden:first").parent().toggleClass("radio radioOff");$("#signup-form .hidden:last").parent().toggleClass("radio radioOff");$("#signup-form .hidden:first").closest("li").addClass("active");$("#signup-form .hidden:last").closest("li").removeClass("active");`

Comment: firefox giving SyntaxError: unterminated string literal  

$("#signup-form

Comment: I tried to run code via console.log. It is working perfectly.

Comment: yes but when i check that radio button mannually it displays username and pasword but its not happening when i tried using console

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>   
<div class="radioOff">
<input id="" class="hidden" type="radio">
<label for="">already a member</label>
<span class="identity">identify</span>
</div>
<script>
$('#document').ready(function () {
    $(".hidden").attr("checked", true);
});
</script>
```

Comment: sorry Anoop the script is not working in firefox console .I tried for following site
http://www.degriftour-selection.fr/login.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
$(function(){
    $(".hidden").attr("checked", true);
});
```

You have used empty `id=""`, you can add id value  or you can use to get using classname.

```
  <input id="myRadio" class="hidden" type="radio">
```

Jquery,

```
 $("#myRadio").attr("checked", true);
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("myRadio").checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $(".hidden").attr("checked", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to reference to empty ID because it'll be ignored in DOM.

One option is to use `getElementsByClassName()` to get all elements and then iterate through them. Second option (better) will be adding proper ID attribute and use it then.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, I believe the `querySelector` is supported from IE8+ and on all other major browsers.

```
var elem = document.querySelector(".radioOff"),
    radio = (elem.firstElementChild||elem.firstChild);

radio.checked = true;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upUZ9/)

Updated according to comment. To select the checkbox *déjà membr* you could use the JQuery selector (as the page includes JQuery 1.7.2)

```
$('.radioOff').find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Jonathan i want to select déjà membr not MRS . Can you please give correct answer?

Comment: Please see my revised answer. The JQuery should be within the page load function or JQuery document ready `$(document).ready(function() {$('.radioOff').find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);});`

Comment: Jonathan when i run this improved answer of your in firefox console for following website
http://www.degriftour-selection.fr/login.html
it did not work

Comment: The code does work but it changes the **hidden** input. To change both the hidden input and the visible *graphic* of the checkbox you will need to do something like this `var $radioOff = $('.radioOff'), $radio = $('.radio'); $radioOff.find('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true); $radioOff.removeClass('radioOff').addClass('radio'); $radio.addClass('radioOff').removeClass('radio');`

Comment: It is getting clicked but after click user name and password fields are not appearing

Comment: You will need to call the function that makes these changes or trigger the event which would call this function. I would contact the site owner to obtain this information.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it is working perfectly.... please try from your side...

```
<div class="radioOff">
    <input id="" class="hidden" type="radio" />
    <label for="">already a member</label>
    <span class="identity">identify</span>
</div>
```

and then after use below jquery code (you also need to add jQuery file reference)...

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hidden").attr("checked", true);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry Vishal I can not do any change in UI code its third party website

Comment: @pravinkottawar I have use getElementsByClassName('') function to fix it, which suggested by Elon to you already... Thank you

Comment: @pravinkottawar getElementsByClassName('') can be retrieve multiple controls, so you need to access each control same as array. like "document.getElementsByClassName("hidden")[0]"

Comment: I can not add
 <input type="button" id="test" value="Test" onclick="return TestFn()" />

Comment: @pravinkottawar could you please let me know your limitation of code changes and limitation to add code...?

Comment: The code which is there on site can not be modified
http://www.degriftour-selection.fr/login.html
and i need to choose déjà membre using java script

Comment: I tried in console of firefox for some website its not working . it is returning some object

Comment: @pravinkottawar Have you checked those pages included JQuery file reference?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of this code in ur js:

```
return ($('input[type=radio]:checked').size() > 0);
```

Or

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName("hidden").checked)
```

Comment: Nisha its not working in console for site
http://www.degriftour-selection.fr/login.html